# onDetach not called for fragment?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, activity-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

I write an code to launch Activity A to Activity B. Both Activity A and B has fragment implementation.

Scenario: If Activity A frequently launch Activity B which contain Fragment, then most of times it missed Fragment.onDetach..I checked with log, normally it give me following override method log:

1. onAttach
2. List item
3. OnCreatView
4. onViewCreate then press device Back Button
5. onPause
6. onStop
7. onDestroyView
8. onDetach

now I press device Back button from Activity B which again launch Activity A then it launch Activity B and repeat same sequence frequently, then log sequence get change in following order:

1. onAttach
2. List item
3. OnCreatView
4. onViewCreate then press device Back Button
5. onPause
6. onStop
7. onDestroyView and repeat with
8. onAttach without onDetach

some times it repeat same behaviour after onPause also.

I am using

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commitAllowingStateLoss(); to add fragment in Activity.
```

Is there anything I am missing..any suggestion ?

Comment: All fragment transactions are asynchronous, maybe fragmentmanager optimises that behaviour and does not detach fragment just to reattach it right after that?

Comment: @pskink to relaunch same fragment again..any suggestion!

Comment: relaunch? sorry, i dont get it

Comment: @dominik4142 yes might be, but what if wanted to call explicit onDetach call ?

Comment: @pskink since activity share some common data and that should update by only one client at a time...but here for same class two instance get created.

Answer (score 0):

A fragment is detached after it is destroyed. what u have done is dettached directly after destroying view.
Remember destroying and destroying view are two different things in fragment.
So try onDestroyView, then onDestroy and then onDetach.

Comment: onDetach is not called when fragment is destroyed but when it stops to be connected to any activity! Fragments can (and should) be preserved for later use, stored by fragment manager.